# Position absolute div inside overflow x auto div is getting clipped

Tags: position, overflow, absolute

[image] I have created a div with overflow x auto and a child div which has position absolute. Child div is getting clipped.

I tried using z-index but its not working. How to override overflow x auto and make child div visible. Please help me. Thanks in advance.